# Adding voltage divider in line to stereo speakers

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

New to site. Vintage hi-fi enthusiast. I have a pair of bi-polar speakers I want to modify. I would like the ability to lower the volume on the REAR drivers only so they are at 50% volume of the front drivers. Would adding a voltage divider (or better yet a volume pot) accomplish what I am looking to do?  The speakers are 8ohm and amp is rated to 4ohm with 125 watts per channel. Any details on type of pot or resistors and how to wire is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Uhm, do you mean "new to site"?

Comment: I presume that you're driving the speakers with a 2 channel stereo amp?

Comment: If at all possible, you want to insert the attenuation *before* the power amp, not after it. After it, the resistors will need to be rated for (at least) the power the amp can provide, so in this case you'd want resistors rated for (again, at least) 125 watts. Many amps have (on the order of) 3 dB of dynamic head room. If that's the case here, it means the amp can provide up to 250 watts. That's only for a short period of time (~20 ms) but that's often long enough to toast the resistors, so you may need to plan for it.

Comment: If you can insert the resistors before the amp, you're typically dealing with 2V P-P into a ~15k (or maybe even more) load, so even really tiny resistors that can't carry any appreciable power are perfectly fine.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: that would only work if there are separate amps for the front and the rear. In that case, you can just fiddle with the volume control of the rear amp.

Comment: @Hilmar: That all depends, of course. Many power amps don't have volume controls (mine certainly don't). Considering the (immense) difference in costs involved, he might also consider cutting a couple of traces to insert attenuation inside a multi-channel amplifier.

Comment: @Hilmar is correct.  The speaker is driven by a single amp. My hope was to install attenuators inside the speaker cabinet, either before the crossover or after crossover and before each driver

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how fancy you want to get and how your speaker is internally wired.

Let's assume front and back are wired  in parallel (i.e. 2 16 Ohm drivers). In this case it's easiest to just use a power resistor in series with the rear driver.

First you need to decide what 50% volume means: perceived loudness or acoustic power generated? To get half the loudness you want to reduce the power by a factor of 10. For half power, you want to reduce it by a factor of 2. I'm guessing you may want something in between, maybe -6dB or quarter power.

This number will help you to calculate the resistor value. For quarter power, you want the same as the driver impedance, so 16 Ohms in this case. If you are not sure, you can try a adjustable power resistor. Maybe something like this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-huntington-electric-inc/AVT10006E50R00KE/AVT100-50-ND/257641

Keep in mind though that the driver has a complex impedance and that any type of resistor (adjustable or not ) will not only change the gain but also the overall frequency response. Getting this dialed in requires actual analysis, measurement and real circuit design. The adjustable resistors also have a fair bit of inductance as well. This may help or harm, depending on the specific properties of your driver and the resistors being used.

If your box is wired in series, things get more complicated, so we won't go there, unless we have to.

Comment: Adding a simple series resistor will have bad side effects, since it changes the dampening. You are quite likely to see unexpected peaks or resonance doing this. The correct way (if you are dealing with the power audio output) is to put an audio step transformer in place. This might help: http://jensen-transformers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Audio-Transformers-Chapter.pdf   ...or products such as this: https://www.amazon.com/Atlas-Sound-AT100-Mounted-Attenuator/dp/B0002V1RPO

Comment: I removed drivers to check impedance.  All rated at 8 ohms. Based on the below it sounds like they are in parallel.  “manufacturer states the impedance of the BP8 and its companion bipolar systems as "compatible with 8-ohm outputs." That characterization is probably justified by the system's relatively high sensitivity (90db)Nonetheless, we measured a minimum impedance of 3.2 ohms at 240 Hz and dips to approximately 4 ohms at several other frequencies. The crossover to the tweeter appeared to be at about 3 kHz, judging from impedance and group-delay measurements.”

Comment: What about this? https://www.parts-express.com/speaker-l-pad-attenuator-100w-mono-1-shaft-8-ohm--260-265?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pla